# Creating a tree in Java

Tags: java, tree

I wrote the following tree class:

```
public class Tree {

    private TreeNode root;


    private static class TreeNode {
        private Pair<String, Float> data;
        private TreeNode leftNode;
        private TreeNode rightNode;

        private TreeNode( Pair<String, Float> data, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
            this.data = data;
            this.leftNode = left;
            this. rightNode = right;
        }
    }
}
```

The following input:

```
"<Hello, 123>"
"<Hi, 1234>"
"<John, 42142>"
"null"
"<Chris, null>"
"<Peter, null>"
"null"
```

And now, i want to write a function that takes this input as an `ArrayList`, like this:

```
ArrayList<Pair<String,Float> input = {"<Hello, 123>", "<Hi, 1234>", "<John, 42142>", "null", "Chris, null", "Peter, null", "null"};
```

And creates a `Tree` using the type defined above.

NOTE: if in some position of the array the value is `null`, it means there should be no node there.

Here's what i've done so far:

```
public createTree(ArrayList<Pair<String, Float>> treeAsVector) {

    int nodes = treeAsVector.size();

    root = new TreeNode(treeAsVector.get(0), null,null);

     for (int i = 1; i < treeAsVector.size(); i++) {

        if(treeAsVector.get(i) == null)
            i++;//skips the node
        else
            //not sure what to do here

}

}
```

I need help, because i'm not understanding very well how i'm supposed to create the tree, because every `TreeNode` will require two additional `TreeNode's`, meaning i always have to see one step ahead...

UPDATE:

The mapping to the tree should be done in levels like this:

```
                     TreeNode
                      (root) 
          TreeNode             TreeNode
             2                     3
 TreeNode       TreeNode  
    4               5
```

if a value in the ArrayList is null, it is not represented.

Comment: left and right nodes can be null, until you have them. what you need I think is a getter and a setter for them

Comment: @Leo i've written an update in order to explain how the mapping is done from the ArrayList to the tree. Can you show me what you mean ?

Comment: well, it seem that your treenode, instead of keeping the children, should instead keep the parent value

Comment: @Leo i cannot change the Tree type

Comment: not sure why the downvotes. it's a well written and thought out question

Comment: @WillSherwood My guess is because it's a question about a pretty elementary programming concept, but I'm with you. It doesn't deserve the hate.

Comment: @WillSherwood i don't understand either... at least the people who voted down should have the sense to explain why. That way next time i ask a question, i would not make the same mistake. Although i think this is question is pretty well asked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void generateTree(ArrayList<Pair<String , Float>> vector){
    //todo holds all nodes that haven't yet had their children assigned
    ArrayList<TreeNode> todo = new ArrayList<>();
    todo.add(new TreeNode(vector.remove(0) , null , null));
    TreeNode root = todo.get(0);

    while(!todo.isEmpty() && !vector.isEmpty())
    {
        TreeNode node = todo.remove(0);

        if(node == null)
            continue;

        //generate the children for the current node
        TreeNode left = vector.get(0) == null ? null : new TreeNode(vector.get(0) , null , null);
        TreeNode right = vector.get(1) == null ? null : new TreeNode(vector.get(1) , null , null);

        vector.remove(0);
        vector.remove(0);

        node.leftNode = left;
        node.rightNode = right;

        //left and right haven't yet had their children assigned
        //queue them, so that they will be processed as soon as the
        //rest of the queue before them has been processed
        todo.add(left);
        todo.add(right);
    }
}
```

During this process, `vector` will be emptied!!! This can be avoided by using a counter instead of removing the content. This algorithm should work for unbalanced trees aswell. Basic idea is to add all nodes to a queue. This way all nodes can be processed ordered by their level.

Comment: I had to add this line, in order to check for null values in the first element, and for your code to work, but thanks, good answer!   `int i = 0; while(vecArv.get(i) == null) vecArv.remove(0);`